# discrete math probability question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

To find an object X, one needs to search linearly through two lists: L1 of 50 elements and L2 of 40 elements. All the elements from both lists are distinct. The probability of X∈L1 is 40%, of X∈L2 is 30%, and there is 30% probability of X being absent altogether.

You are to decide whether searching first L1 or first L2 would lead to a smaller expected value of the number of accesses.

I think ii should select from L1 first as it got high probability to get the right answer,
but i am not sure the calculation behind this, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: you should consider the fact that L2 is shorter, hence searching in L2 requires less time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search $L_1$ first, the expected number of checks is $0.4\cdot 25 +0.3(50+20)+0.3\cdot 90=58.$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, i really want to know how to form this equation, do you where i can find the common formula for this kind of question? thank you

Comment: The first term is the chance it is in L1 times the expected number to look at. The second is the chance it is in L2 times the 50 you checked in L1 plus half L2

Comment: so if I search L2 first, the formula would be: 0.3*20 + 0.4(40+25) + 0.3 * 90 = 59, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is right

Comment: What about the expected value when you search $L_2$ first? From this only, one cannot conclude it's better to start with $L_1$!

Comment: @Ragnar I was leaving that to OP, who did it correctly

Comment: @RossMillikan, then it's OK. (didn't read the comments well enough I guess)

Answer (score 3):

The probability of an element in $L_1$ being $X$ is $\frac{40\%}{50}=0.8\%$. For $L_2$ this is $\frac{30\%}{40}=0.75\%$. It is thus better to search $L_1$ first.